# ! Missing \endgroup inserted

Tags: r, latex

I run the latex equation array in R markdown and got the error message when knit to PDF.

```
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\dfrac{12n}{k(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(R_{.j}-\dfrac{k+1}{2}\right)^{2}\\
 &=&\left[\dfrac{12}{nk(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{k}R_{j}^{2}\right]-3n(k+1)\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `eqnarray` environment places the content already on math mode - don't wrap it in `$$...$$`

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
---


\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\dfrac{12n}{k(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(R_{.j}-\dfrac{k+1}{2}\right)^{2}\\
 &=&\left[\dfrac{12}{nk(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{k}R_{j}^{2}\right]-3n(k+1)
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mean in R markdown or in Latex?

Comment: @Pai both......